# Excel VBA macro to autocomplete column copying the above value

Tags: vba, excel

i have an excel document and i want to write a macro to complete dhe column with the value of a cell. for example:

[figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoY9c.png)

In figure 1 i have value1 in column A. I want to have a visual basic button that when i click on it it automatically completes the remaining cells of that column with value1 until it finds a non empty cell. in column b i have value3 value4 and value5 in bold black. when i hit the button the vb code automatically completes the cells with te red values. Sorry for my english, it is not my native language. To summarize, at the begining i have only the black values, when i click the button it should automatically add the red values. Can you help me please? I have this code:

```
Sub split()
Dim columns  As Range, i As Long

Set columns = Selection

i = 1

For i = 1 To columns.Rows.Count
    If columns.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
        columns.Cells(i, 1).Value = columns.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

It does the job only for the selected column, i want it to apply to the entire workbook. How can i change this?

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried? If you do, please include that in your question so we can see what changes need to be made :)

Comment: If you would like someone to write code for you then I recommend you hire a developer.

Comment: thank you guys, i really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

How does this work? It should be a little quicker than looping through a cell, as we can use `SpecialCells()` to select blank cells in one go:

```
Sub copyDown()
Dim lastRow As Long, firstRow As Long, lastCol As Long, i As Long
Dim rng As Range, totalCell As Range
Dim cols As Variant

cols = Split(InputBox("What columns do you want? Use space to separate." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "I.e. 'A C D F'"), " ")

'Set totalCell = Range("A:A").Find(what:="SubTotal :", LookIn:=xlPart)

If Not Application.IsNA(Application.Match("SubTotal *", Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
    Set totalCell = Cells(Application.Match("SubTotal :", Range("A:A"), 0), 1)
End If

For i = LBound(cols) To UBound(cols)
    firstRow = Cells(1, cols(i)).End(xlDown).Row

    Set rng = Range(Cells(firstRow, cols(i)), Cells(totalCell.Row - 1, cols(i)))
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=r[-1]C"
    rng.Value = rng.Value
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much sir. I am in mobile now and cannot try your code. Tomorrow i will try it, hopefully your code will do the work and i will mark your answer as the solution too. You are right about last rows, i will clarify it too. Thanx again sir, i really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sir let say i need to use first 5 columns (it would be great if i can write code to select columnd A and C and D for example), and i need to populate the sheet until a row that contains the word 'total'. For more please see the attached image in this link: [illustration screen](http://imgur.com/a/1PGs6) . Thanx in advance sir!

Comment: thank you for your help. I really liked the idea of having a window dialog asking which columns to select but i find a runtime error :                                 Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set                                                     using the debug option it tells me that this is the line causing the problem   `Set rng = Range(Cells(firstRow, cols(i)), Cells(totalCell.Row - 1, cols(i)))`      Do you have any idea? Thank you sir, you are helping me a lot.

Comment: @user2357735 when you typed in the columns, how did you do it? It should be letters separated by a space, eg `A C D AB`

Comment: Sir when i remove the input box and i do it manually like this   `cols = Split(A, B, C)` , i get a runtime error 13 type mismatch at this row.   `firstRow = Cells(1, cols(i)).End(xlDown).Row` . Do you have any idea how to solve this, i can manually insert column names in the code without using the box window. Thank you!